# how to check the Type used by a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the case where you have various classes derived from `MyFaultBase`.  So when your web service needs to indicate fault it throws an exception of type `FaultException<MySpecificFault>`.

After catching this exception, how can you determine whether the `FaultException<T>` is bound to a class derived from `MyFaultBase`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a global way :

```
    public class SpecificClass : BaseClass
    {
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
    }

    public class TemplatedClass<T>
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var templateInstance = new TemplatedClass<SpecificClass>();
        var @true = typeof (BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(templateInstance.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);

        var templateInstance2 = new TemplatedClass<int>();
        var @false = typeof (BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(templateInstance2.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the generic type arguments using [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Then your `IsExceptionBoundToType` method may look something like this:

```
public static bool IsExceptionBoundToType(FaultException fe, Type checkType)
{
    bool isBound = false;
    Type feType = fe.GetType();
    if (feType.IsGenericType && feType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FaultException<>))
    {
        Type faultType = feType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        isBound = checkType.IsAssignableFrom(faultType);
    }

    return isBound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no simple way to is-check a generic class; likely due to the flexibility of the generic parameter.  Here is a solution:

```
public static bool IsExceptionBoundToType(FaultException fe, Type checkType)
{
   bool isBound = false;

   // Check to see if the FaultException is a generic type.
   Type feType = fe.GetType();
   if (feType.IsGenericType && feType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FaultException<>))
   {
      // Check to see if the Detail property is a class of the specified type.
      PropertyInfo detailProperty = feType.GetProperty("Detail");
      if (detailProperty != null)
      {
         object detail = detailProperty.GetValue(fe, null);
         isBound = checkType.IsAssignableFrom(detail.GetType());
      }
   }

   return (isBound);
}
```

Catch the exception and check it like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   if ((ex is FaultException) && IsExceptionBoundToType(ex, typeof(MyFaultBase)))
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```